# Unity GameObjects are not rendering after Instantiation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a simple game for one of my college modules.
When I click with the left mouse button I need a boxing glove to appear.

The problem I am having, is that the gloves are not rendering, the appear in the hierarchy but do not show on the screen, see images

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
public class script_CreateBoxingGlove : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject BoxingGlove;

    void Start () {

    }   

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            var position = Input.mousePosition;
            Instantiate (BoxingGlove, position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: In a case like this I would suggest to not instantiate the glove over and over again put enable and disable it instead (and have it be a child of the boxer if there is one).

Comment: you must not call the class script_CreateBoxingGlove.  it won't work.  change it to CreateBoxingGlove and ensure you change the filename also

Comment: And yes, your problem is the position because `Input.mousePosition` a is screen position, not a world position. Use `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)`.

Comment: @GunnarB. I did that and it has now placed it at weird coordinates, http://postimg.org/image/41bkdeekt/

Comment: The `-10` on z is the z of the camera, probably should be 0. Just put a `position.z = 0` or what you find fitting by testing.

Comment: Lol the answer  you selected is what @GunnarB. said. You said it didn't work for you but then selected the-same answer....

Comment: @Programmer the variable was different

Comment: NO its not. Do *Ctr+F* and paste `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)` . from @GunnarB, you will that both his answer that guy are the-same. That's fine though. I am just pointing it out to you to thank @GunnarB for his help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the image links have some ridiculous ads in them.

Comment: @JoeBlow I think the post is already closed when you select an answer...not sure

Comment: There is a slite difference in the answer. `position` is declared as `Vector2` which gets rid of the z problem right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Input.mousePosition` is the position **on the screen** of the mouse, not in world coordinates (it is documented [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html)).

So you have to convert it to world coordinates before using it as the position. The instantiate statement should be something like this

```
Vector2 position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
Instantiate (BoxingGlove, position, Quaternion.identity);
```

This uses the camera in the hierarchy that is tagged as "MainCamera" to convert. So to make this code work, you will have to make sure there is a camera tagged like that in your hierarchy.